# Errors while compiling dhrystone in unix

Tags: c++, c, linux, performance, unix

I am new in using benchmarks and makefiles. I have downloaded Dhrystone benchmark from the below link and I am trying to compile it, but I am facing weird errors. I tried to solve it,but I am unsuccessful. Can someone help me in running the dhrystone benchmark? 
Below are the 2 different ways that I tried to compile. But both are giving the same error result  :(

Link: http://fossies.org/unix/privat/old/dhrystone-2.1.tar.gz/

**compile commands tried**:

```
gcc -g dhry.h dhry_1.c dhry_2.c -o dhrystonex

make all
```

error:

```
gcc -O -DTIMES           -DHZ=60                dhry_1.c dhry_2.c  -o gcc_dry2
dhry_1.c:31:18: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
dhry_1.c:48:17: error: conflicting types for ‘times’
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/times.h:49:16: note: previous declaration of ‘times’ was here
dhry_1.c: In function ‘main’:
dhry_1.c:98:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’ [enabled by default]
dhry_1.c:124:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
make: *** [gcc_dry2] Error 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the following changes. A line with a `-` before it indicates one you should remove. A line with a `+` before it indicates one you should add. In total, you will replace two lines (by preceding them with `//`) and add one new line (a `#include`):

```
    diff -bup orig/dhry_1.c new/dhry_1.c
    --- orig/dhry_1.c       2012-03-30 11:30:41.984107303 -0700
    +++ new/dhry_1.c        2012-03-30 11:31:29.256002567 -0700
    @@ -28,7 +28,7 @@ char            Ch_1_Glob,
     int             Arr_1_Glob [50];
     int             Arr_2_Glob [50] [50];

    -extern char     *malloc ();
    +// extern char     *malloc ();
     Enumeration     Func_1 ();
       /* forward declaration necessary since Enumeration may not simply be int */

    @@ -45,7 +45,7 @@ Enumeration     Func_1 ();

     #ifdef TIMES
     struct tms      time_info;
    -extern  int     times ();
    +// extern  int     times ();
                                     /* see library function "times" */
     #define Too_Small_Time (2*HZ)
                                     /* Measurements should last at least about 2 seconds */
    diff -bup orig/dhry.h new/dhry.h
    --- orig/dhry.h 2012-03-30 11:30:41.984107303 -0700
    +++ new/dhry.h  2012-03-30 11:31:29.256002567 -0700
    @@ -392,6 +392,7 @@
     /* General definitions: */

     #include <stdio.h>
    +#include <string.h>
                                     /* for strcpy, strcmp */

     #define Null 0
```

Comment: Oh! How simple it is! you did my work with in seconds. I still didn't understand Why I missed such a simple compilation errors..  Any how Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sreeharivallu : It's time to take 2 minutes of your time and accept answers for questions that solved your problem ( http://i.imgur.com/uqJeW.png )  AND upvote other answers that helped your situation ( http://i.imgur.com/kygEP.png ). Good luck to all.