# Interpreting the Dhrystone Benchmark results on Modern PC

Tags: c, benchmarking

First I'll give a run down on what I did.

I downloaded dhry.h dhry_1.c and dhry_2.c from here: 
http://giga.cps.unizar.es/~spd/src/other/dhry/

Then I made some corrections (so that I would compile) according to this:

https://github.com/maximeh/buildroot/blob/master/package/dhrystone/dhrystone-2-HZ.patch

And this

[Errors while compiling dhrystone in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948508/errors-while-compiling-dhrystone-in-unix)

I've compiled the files with the following command line:

gcc dhry_1.c dhry_2.c -O2 -o run

I finally entered the number of runs to be 1000000000

And waited. I compiled with four different optimization levels and I got these values of DMIPS (According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhrystone this is the Dhrystones per Second divided by 1757):

O0: 8112 O1: 16823.9 O2: 22977.5  O3: 23164.5 (these represent the compiler flags like -O2 is optimization level two and O0 is none).

This would give the following DMIPS/MHz (base frequency for my processor is 3.4 GHz):

2.3859   4.9482   6.7581   6.8131

However, I get the feelign tha 6.7 is way to low. According to what I've read an A15 has between 3.5 to 4 DMIPS/MHz and a third generation I7 only has double that? Shouldn't it be a lot higher?

Can anyone tell me from my procedure if they can see that I might have done something wrong? Or maybe I'm interpretting the results incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Except with a broad brush treatment, you cannot compare benchmark results produced by different compilers. As the design authority of the first standard benchmark (Whetstone), I can advise that it even less safe to include comparisons with results from a computer manufacturer’s in-house compiler. In minicomputer days, manufacturers found that sections of the Whetstone benchmark could be optimised out, to double the score. I arranged for changes and more detailed results to avoid and later highlight over optimisation.

Below are example results on PCs from my original (1990’s) Dhrystone Benchmarks. For details, more results and (free) execution and source files see:

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/dhrystone%20results.htm

Also included, and compiled from the same source code, are results from a later MS compiler and some via Linux and on Android, via ARM CPUs, plus one for an Intel Atom, via Houdini compatibility layer. I prefer the term VAX MIPS instead to DMIPS, as the 1757 divisor is the result on  DEC VAX 11/780. Anyway, MIPS/MHz calculations are also shown. Note differences due to compilers and the particularly low ratios on Android ARM CPUs.

```
                          Dhry1   Dhry1   Dhry2   Dhry2     Dhry2
                            Opt   NoOpt     Opt   NoOpt       Opt
                            VAX     VAX     VAX     VAX     MIPS/
CPU                 MHz    MIPS    MIPS    MIPS    MIPS       MHz

AMD 80386            40    17.5    4.32    13.7    4.53       0.3
80486 DX2            66    45.1      12    35.3    12.4       0.5
Pentium             100     169    31.8     122    32.2       1.2
Pentium Pro         200     373    92.4     312    91.9       1.6
Pentium II          300     544     132     477     136       1.6
Pentium III         450     846     197     722     203       1.6
Pentium 4          1900    2593     261    2003     269       1.1
Atom               1666    2600     772    1948     780       1.2
Athlon 64          2211    5798    1348    4462    1312       2.0
Core 2 Duo 1 CP    2400    7145    1198    6446    1251       2.7
Phenom II 1 CP     3000    9462    2250    7615    2253       2.5
Core i7 4820K      3900   14776    2006   11978    2014       3.1

Later Intel Compiler
Pentium 4          1900    2613            1795               0.9
Athlon 64          2211    6104            3720               1.7
Core 2 Duo         2400    8094            5476               2.3
Phenom II          3000    9768            6006               2.0
Core i7 4820K      3900   15587           10347               2.7

Linux Ubuntu GCC Compiler
Atom               1666    5485    1198    2055    1194       1.2
Athlon 64          2211    9034    2286    4580    2347       2.1
Core 2 Duo         2400   13599    3428    5852    3348       2.4
Phenom II          3000   13406    3368    6676    3470       2.2
Core i7 4820K      3900   29277    7108   16356    7478       4.2

ARM Android NDK
926EJ               800                     356     196       0.4
v7-A9              1500                    1650     786       1.1
v7-A15             1700                    3189    1504       1.9

Atom Houdini       1866                    1840    1310       1.0
```

Comment: (OT) Have you got any other interesting stories about the history of benchmarks? (other than what's in wikipedia). My first PC had a benchmark with Dhrystones and KWhetstones. I figured there was some sort of pun going on (dry - wet) but other than that it was just a bunch of numbers.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. So I can't compare DMIPS scores with different compilers. That explains it. I had actually found your page looking and found the the number that you provided for GCC where the same as mine. However I then found this guy: https://blog.fierydragonlord.com/index.php?/archives/5-Dhrystone-Running-a-25-year-old-benchmark-on-modern-hardware.html
That got the exact same DMIPS score on a slower i7. So according to you the difference is the compiler? (He did say he used a Visual Studio Compiler). By the way, thank you for your answer

Comment: One last thing. One of the reasons I was trying to understand this benchmark is because I want to run it in a couple of different (very unknown, specific) microprocessors. However since they belong to two different companies and each provide their own version of gcc to compile for their microprocessor, comparing this benchmark would be invalid, right? Becuase they are essentially two different compilers...

Comment: You did not say which i7. I found that at least all single CPU benchmarks run at the Turbo Boost GHz. It is the Dhrystone 1 results that are similar to yours. Dhry 2 was produced as Dhry 1 could be over optimised.

Comment: Not invalid but treated with care. If you run with all Opt levels, you can have more confidence.

Comment: Matt - Whetstone came first with floating point. Dhrystone has no floating point, hence the pun Dhry.

Comment: My processor is an i7 3770 which runs at 3.4 GHz base. With level two optimization of Dhry2 I got 22977.5 which is very much like this score:
Core i7 4820K 64b  Ub  $$$1  32659   8436   23607  8481 (from your webpage). The last two values are very similar to my first two values (optimized and non optimized)

Comment: The difference is that the values you posted here seem to be for 32 bit compilation while I compile for 64 bits. Then the values match up, I think.

Comment: 3770 has the same Turbo Boost Speed  as 4820K at 3.9 GHz. I forgot to ask about 64 bit compilation and should have noticed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69391/discussion-between-aarelovich-and-roy-longbottom).